# Unable to start Sunspot Solr in production

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm having a hard time starting up Sunspot Solr in production. When I try to run Sunspot in the foreground from within my Rails app with `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run`, I can see the following message:

> The currently defined JAVA_HOME
>   (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin) refers to a location where
>   Java could not be found.  Aborting. Either fix the JAVA_HOME variable
>   or remove it from the environment so that the system PATH will be
>   searched.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. I have already installed openjdk-7-jre and I can see that my /etc/environment file contains:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin"
```

if I `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin` which seems correct as I can see a java binary in that directory. I'm really quite stumped and can't figure out why Sunspot Solr isn't starting up in production.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: running `Sunspot::Solr::Java.installed?` from the Rails console gives me `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting `$JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` in /etc/environment. Then had to create the following:

```
mkdir -p /my/app/solr/production/data/index
mkdir -p /my/app/solr/production/data/tlog
touch /my/app/solr/production/core.properties
```

Then added the following to the `core.properties` file:

```
name=production
configSet=sunspot
dataDir=./data
```

All seems to be working properly now :)